# Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS slow disk IO in single directory

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, io, read-write

I have an AWS server running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS that has a super slow I/O when writing to a directory. The webserver is running Nginx 1.14.1 and php7.0-fpm on a single SSD partion:

```
root@ip-10-0-5-223:/home/ubuntu# sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME    FSTYPE  SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
xvda            100G
└─xvda1 ext4    100G /          cloudimg-rootfs
```

When writing to my /var/web (/var/www more commonly used), my disk IO is extremely slow compared to other directories. If I copy a fresh Wordpress install to a directory inside anywhere in /home/ or /var/ my IO speed is extremely quick and consuming very little CPU and memory.

```
top - 23:03:18 up 1 day,  7:54,  2 users,  load average: 0.52, 0.63, 0.71
Tasks: 163 total,   2 running, 161 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.4 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.1 st
KiB Mem : 16430960 total, 13827148 free,   336940 used,  2266872 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 15644724 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
11209 www-data  20   0  512832 113412  73056 S   6.3  0.7   0:39.47 php-fpm7.0
11990 www-data  20   0  814560 109252  70616 R   3.3  0.7   0:13.13 php-fpm7.0
11993 www-data  20   0  489944  91344  73772 S   0.7  0.6   0:14.54 php-fpm7.0
11994 www-data  20   0  805180 112676  83184 S   0.7  0.7   0:12.00 php-fpm7.0
12348 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.7  0.0   0:01.26 kworker/3:1H
11988 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.91 kworker/2:0H
    1 root      20   0  119732   5320   3440 S   0.0  0.0   0:06.64 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.41 ksoftirqd/0
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   1:52.96 rcu_sched
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.04 migration/0
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.26 watchdog/0
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.22 watchdog/
```

The disk read and write speeds are so fast that I can't even snap them in dstat.

But when I write to anything inside my /var/web/ directory, my CPU wait time is etremely slow and it takes about 30 seconds to complete the process.

```
Tasks: 160 total,   1 running, 159 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.5 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 83.4 id, 13.4 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.1 st
KiB Mem : 16430960 total, 13828044 free,   363464 used,  2239452 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 15618252 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
11211 www-data  20   0  818068 125568  83196 S   9.0  0.8   0:49.70 php-fpm7.0
11987 www-data  20   0  495908  98248  74900 S   3.0  0.6   0:29.39 php-fpm7.0
13120 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   1.0  0.0   0:02.01 kworker/3:2H
11990 www-data  20   0  797912 103656  82520 S   0.7  0.6   0:25.98 php-fpm7.0
13218 root      20   0   20232   2492   2332 D   0.7  0.0   0:00.06 cp
 3886 www-data  20   0  257088  18612   5368 S   0.3  0.1   0:29.71 nginx
11992 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:02.37 kworker/1:0H
    1 root      20   0  119732   5320   3440 S   0.0  0.0   0:06.68 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.03 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.42 ksoftirqd/0
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   1:53.83 rcu_sched
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.04 migration/0
```

Here is the dstat report:

```
----total-cpu-usage---- -dsk/total- -net/total- ---paging-- ---system--
usr sys idl wai hiq siq| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw
  3   1  96   1   0   0| 529k  790k|   0     0 |   0     0 |3686  3416
  1   0  99   0   0   0|   0    24k|  36k   32k|   0     0 | 426   336
  2   1  95   3   0   0|   0     0 | 217k  224k|   0     0 |2359  2508
  3   1  84  12   0   0|   0     0 | 284k  544k|   0     0 |4421  4629
  2   1  85  13   0   0|  16k    0 | 231k  637k|   0     0 |3613  3562
  0   0  85  14   0   0|   0     0 |  58k  729k|   0     0 |1044  1133
  0   0  87  13   0   0|   0     0 |  64k  391k|   0     0 |1238  1307
  0   0  87  13   0   0|   0    80k|  63k  567k|   0     0 |1193  1272
  0   0  86  14   0   0|   0     0 |  62k  623k|   0     0 |1190  1249
  4   1  84  12   0   0|   0    16k| 251k  575k|   0     0 |1797  1771
  2   0  85  13   0   0|   0     0 | 110k 1024k|   0     0 |1407  1235
  0   0  86  14   0   0|   0     0 |  60k  739k|   0     0 |1199  1204
  0   0  86  14   0   0|   0     0 |  61k  627k|   0     0 |1156  1208
  4   1  84  12   0   0|   0     0 | 227k  426k|   0     0 |2015  1760
  0   0  87  13   0   0|   0    96k|  67k  502k|   0     0 |1261  1350
  1   0  85  14   0   0|   0     0 |  80k  947k|   0     0 |1219  1272
  0   0  88  12   0   0|   0     0 |  70k  558k|   0     0 |1305  1380
  1   0  88  11   0   0|   0     0 |  87k  665k|   0     0 |1516  1515
  2   1  87  10   0   0|   0     0 | 152k  290k|   0     0 |1883  1753
  0   1  87  12   0   0|   0     0 |  68k  890k|   0     0 |1272  1354
  0   0  88  11   0   0|   0     0 |  71k  353k|   0     0 |1224  1413
  4   0  83  13   0   0|   0    24k| 216k 1258k|   0     0 |1766  1589
  1   0  88  12   0   0|   0     0 |  84k  444k|   0     0 |1392  1471
  1   1  88  10   0   0|   0     0 | 109k  189k|   0     0 |1641  1662
```

That particular directory is very large as it contains quite a few websites. Could that be all there is to it? Something is tying up a bit of the CPU and really increasing those CPU wait times, but I though I should be able to replicate by trying the same file transfer somewhere also in the /var/ directory.

I can provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 0):

After digging and digging I figured it out. It turns out the directory in question was actually a mount point to a AWS elastic file system. I inherited this from an old sysadmin who left no documentation on it at all.

So the bottleneck was not performance I/O at all. It was Read/write from the AWS file system.