# Slow rm -rf on linux machine

Tags: azure

When executing `rm -rf /some/folder/*` on a directory with many files, server performance significantly goes down.
Drive is Premium SSD.

Tried different ways of deleting files:
`find --delete`, `rsync` (described here https://www.kinamo.be/en/support/faq/efficiently-remove-a-zillion-files-on-linux-servers). Did not help.

Is there a way to delete many files fast without impact on the performance of the server in general?

Comment: Please quantify "slow".  How many files are you deleting?  How long does it take?

Comment: 116000 files in 2 minutes 30 seconds.

It is azure issue from my experience.
Locally it takes 1 second. Other server providers also 1-3 seconds.

Comment: Do you know if the file system is mounted with `sync` or `dirsync` options?  These could make a significant difference to file deletion.

Comment: > root ~ # mount -l | grep 'dev/sda'
> /dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard) [cloudimg-rootfs]

Comment: The `discard` option can have performance impact.  But to be honest, I don't think StackOverflow is the right site for this question.  I'd ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing of `discard` option helped (Stephen C).

Here is some more info: [Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS slow disk IO in single directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470778/ubuntu-16-04-5-lts-slow-disk-io-in-single-directory)

Comment: How to remove `discard` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/add-disk#trimunmap-support-for-linux-in-azure

Comment: Impact of ext4’s discard option - https://patrick-nagel.net/blog/archives/337